# UWP CalendarView localization

Tags: c#, uwp, calendarview

I've included a CalendarView control in my UWP app, the problem is that I'm not able to find a way to change what is the first day of the week based on the user's settings. Is there a way to automatically change the `FirstDayOfWeek` property based on the settings of the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using [`Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences).

```
Cal.FirstDayOfWeek = GlobalizationPreferences.WeekStartsOn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get the details about system dates

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek;
```

To convert `System.DayOfWeek` to `Windows.Globalization.DayOfWeek`

```
MyCalendarView.FirstDayOfWeek = (Windows.Globalization.DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(Windows.Globalization.DayOfWeek), DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek.ToString());
```

Comment: How do I convert DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek to System.DayOfWeek?